# Using Regex to capture numerics in different form

Tags: regex

We are receiving files sent by Margin Providers which includes the details of the Margin amount assigned to their accounts by honoring a particular format; We receive this as a `*.csv` file content.

sample values are as like this (First row is header):

> DATE(DD/MM/YYYY),CLIENT NAME,CLIENT ID,BORROWING CAPACITY
>   27/11/2019,M/s  S.Smith & SON (PVT) LTD,JKB1234LC,6000000.00
>   11/3/2020,XXXX Bank PLC / Dr. G. Smith,JKB12345LC,"10,000,000"
>   27/11/2019,Mrs. A. Smith & Mrs. A.A.Smith,JKB11223LC,20000000.00
>   11/03/2020,Mr. C. Smith,JKB9087LC,0
>   27/11/2019,Mrs. I.A. Smith,JKB9876LC,0.00

I have used the following `Regex` expression to identify the Account and the Margin Value:

```
(?'Account'JKB[0-9]+LC)(?'Amount',(?<=LC,)\d+\.\d*)
```

It is exactly capturing the Account but there were instances it does not capture the amount because it may be in Thousand separators or no decimal values or even inside single or double quotes etc.

To solve this I am conceptualizing that I can do the following and continue with the same expression listed above:

1. Identify the amount inside the quotes and remove the comma characters
2. Then replace the single quotes or double quotes surrounding the amount and replace
3. Then proceed with the same `Regex` expression

But what I would like to do is build a single `Regex` expression to capture the Account and the Amount, where the Amount can be either inside a quote, double quote, with decimal or without a decimal or in thousand separators. However, I am finding it difficult to accommodate those scenarios into my `Regex` and seek your help.

Here is my working:
https://regex101.com/r/X6aq4g/1

Comment: I'm curious why you want to use a regex considering that most languages have tools for reading CSV files into objects that can be easily manipulated. If you use a particular language for general tasks you might consider adding a tag for that language and inviting readers to give answers that using either use a regex or mainly use the language you identify.

Comment: Is this it?: `('Amount',(?<=LC,)['"]?[0-9\.,])`. I can't test it right now. Can in an hour. Note that it's not possible to filter out the thousands separator. That should be done afterwards.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have implemented a simple `Functions App` in `Azure` with the objective of converting `CSV` to `JSON` as my solutions revolves in Cloud.

Comment: Hey @Jupiter Thank you very much! I was able to build the `Regex` expression as `(?'Account'JKB[0-9]+LC)(?'Amount',(?<=LC,)"?[0-9\.,]+"?)` but would like to check in yours

Comment: @PoulBak you expression did not match all cases :(

Comment: Do you want test if the amount is valid (e.g., match `6,000.00` but not  `60,00.00` or `1,.,6.,,`) or will you accept any string containing any combination of digits, commas and periods?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just want to get the amount part exactly irrespective of it being inside quotes, with thousand separators, etc. Afterward, I did some cleansing of the string such as taking-off the quotes and commas. I will consider string literals like 6,000 or 6,000.00 or 60,00.00 because subsequent to cleansing it will 6000.00. Am I being clear to you?

Comment: That certainly makes task easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one you can use to identify every single block (it avoids corner cases where client names contain LC, like in 'PLC')

`(?'Date'\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d{4}),(?'Client'"[^"]*?"|[^,]*?),(?'Account'[^,]*?),"?(?'Amount'[0-9,.]*)"?`

https://regex101.com/r/R5zZze/1

Details :

- Match Date : one or two digits for day / one or two digits for month / 4 digits for year
- Then a `,` not in Date nor Client
- Match Client : either `"` followed by some chars until the next `"`, *or* some chars that aren't `,`
- Then a `,` not in Client nor Account
- Match Account: some chars that aren't `,` (I only assumed there was no `,` in client id)
- Then a `,` and maybe a `"`, not in Account nor Amount
- Match Amount : any number of digit, dot or comma
- Then an optional `"` (that can be safely removed from the regex)